# Symbol not found error when using Lua C .so module with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, lua

I am trying to get a basic Lua C .so module working with LuaLaTeX.

I am able to run the library using my local Lua interpreter just fine (`lua test.lua`). But when I try to load it inside LuaLaTeX, I get the error as shown below.

The test file is `test.tex`. The Lua package is located in `harfbuzz.sty`, the lua file is `luaharfbuzz.lua`, and the C library code is in `harfbuzz.c`

My environment: Mac OS X, TeXLive 2015 and Lua 5.2.4.

The minimal code example is here:
https://github.com/deepakjois/tex-sandbox/tree/master/luatex-lua-c-bridge

In the code above, I am compiling a file harfbuzz.c to harfbuzz.so. When I load it in my Lua code `lua test.lua`, it works fine. However, when I am loading it using LuaTeX using `lualatex test.tex` it throws an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Error Details:

```
lualatex test.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
…
<snip>
…
(./luaharfbuzz.lua)
! LuaTeX error error loading module 'harfbuzz' from file './harfbuzz.so':
        dlopen(./harfbuzz.so, 6): Symbol not found: _luaL_setfuncs
  Referenced from: ./harfbuzz.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in ./harfbuzz.so
stack traceback:
        [C]: in ?
        [C]: in ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ./luaharfbuzz.lua:2: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }

l.6 \end{luacode*}
```

### Update 1

Here is a comparision of the shared libraries that the lua and luatex binaries on my computer link to. Can that help explain the problem?

```
> otool -L `which lua` `which luatex`
/usr/local/bin/lua:
        /usr/local/lib/liblua.5.2.dylib (compatibility version 5.2.0, current version 5.2.4)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1225.1.1)
        /usr/lib/libedit.3.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
/Library/TeX/texbin/luatex:
        /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.11)
```

### Update 2

It seems the problem is that the luatex binary that comes with TeXLive strips a lot of symbols.

```
nm `which luatex` | grep _luaL_setfu
<…nothing…>
```

But I built my own version of luatex from trunk with the `--nostrip` flag enabled and got this

```
nm build/texk/web2c/luatex | grep _luaL_setfu
00000001002c54d0 T _luaL_setfuncs
```

So does that mean, there is no way to load a dynamically linked .so file with the default luatex on TeXLive 2015, because the `_luaL_setfuncs` cannot be located?

Comment: The expression "But when I try to load it inside LuaLaTex" is not all that clear. Please state which file is the main tex file and what the file dependencies are.

Comment: It works for me on Linux, I only have to replace `glibtool` with `libtool` in in `compile.sh`

Comment: @michal.h21 I am using `glibtool` because I am on OS X, and I wanted to use the GNU toolchain.

Comment: @Mico I added some more clarification.

Comment: I don’t quite understand how the `luatex` binary works. Unlike the lua binary on my system it isn’t linked to liblua.

Comment: @vyom LuaTeX uses an internal copy of Lua, it's quite deliberately not linked to any system version.

Comment: @JosephWright See Update 2 above.

Comment: @michal.h21 Could you please let me know the output of the `nm` tool against your luatex binary on Linux, as shown above in Update 2. Does it find the `_luaL_setfuncs` entry? Maybe your copy is compiled with different options.

Comment: @vyom sure, it is: `nm: /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/luatex: no symbols`.

Comment: I replaced my TeXLive copy of luatex with a freshly compiled copy of luatex binary (with `--nostrip`). I am now able to load my .so file just fine when I run the luatex binary as `luatex --luaonly test.lua`. However, the binary no longer works against tex files. It fails with `(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)`

Comment: @vyom you can try to regenerate the formats with `fmtutil --all`. and maybe the fact that `luatex` doesn't work correctly should be reported as a bug to TL maintainers.

Comment: @michal.h21 I have posted the problem on the mailing list.

Comment: Oh, and `fmtutil --all` gives me another error. It says `undefined control sequence \pdfoutput` when it processes the luatex related formats.

Comment: I've created Lua rock for `justenoughharfbuzz`, you can try whether it creates usable Lua module: https://gist.github.com/michal-h21/26fdc64f86b5cb54977f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turns out to be in the way LuaTeX is compiled when it is distributed. All the symbols are stripped out of the binary, so dynamically linked .so libraries can’t locate the symbols they need.

See the discussion on LuaTeX mailing list: http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2015-November/005440.html

The alternative is to compile your own LuaTeX binary from SVN, building it with the `--nostrip` flag, and then overwriting the existing LuaTeX binary with the new binary. Be careful with this step. Make sure you are compiling the right version of the library (ideally the one bundled with the TeXLive version), and run `fmtutil --byengine luatex` after copying over the binary to update the formats.